# Parsing a mixed-delimiter data set

Tags: php

I've got a source file that contains some data in a few formats that I need to parse. I'm writing an ETL process that will have to match other data.

Most of the data is in the format city, state (US standard, more or less). Some cities are grouped across heavier population areas with multiple cities combined.

Most of the data looks like this (call this 1):

```
Elkhart, IN
```

Some places have multiple cities, delimited by a dash (call this 2):

```
Hickory-Lenoir-Morganton, NC
```

It's still not too complicated when the cities are in different states (call this 3):

```
Steubenville, OH-Weirton, WV
```

This one threw me for a loop; it makes sense but it flushes the previous formats (call this 4):

```
Kingsport, TN-Johnson City, TN-Bristol, VA-TN
```

In that example, `Bristol` is in both `VA` and `TN`. Then there's this (call this 5):

```
Mayagüez/Aguadilla-Ponce, PR
```

I'm okay with replacing the slash with a dash and processing the same as a previous example. That contains a diacritic as well and the rest of my data are diacritic-free. I'm okay with stripping the diacritic off, that seems to be somewhat straightforward in PHP.

Then there's my final example (call this 6):

```
Scranton--Wilkes-Barre--Hazleton, PA
```

The city name contains a dash so the delimiter between city names is a double dash.

What I'd like to produce is, given any of the above examples and a few hundred other lines that follow the same format, an array of `[[city, state],...]` for each so I can turn them into SQL. For example, parsing 4 would yield:

```
[
    ['Kingsport', 'TN'],
    ['Johnson City', 'TN'],
    ['Bristol', 'VA'],
    ['Bristol', 'TN']
]
```

I'm using a standard PHP install, I've got `preg_match` and so on but no PECL libraries. Order is unimportant.

Any thoughts on a good way to do this without a big pile of if-then statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split the input with '-'s and ','s, then delete empty elements in the array. str_replace followed by explode and array_diff (, array ()) should do the trick.
Then identify States - either searching a list or working on the principal that cities don't tend to have 2 upper-case letter names.
Now work through the array. If it's a city, save the name, if it's a state, apply it to the saved cities. Clear the list of cities when you get a city immediately following a state.
Note any exceptions and reformat by hand into a different input.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's interested, I took the answer from @mike and came up with this:

```
function SplitLine($line) {
  // This is over-simplified, just to cover the given case.
  $line = str_replace('ü', 'u', $line);

  // Cover case 6.
  $delimiter = '-';
  if (false !== strpos($line, '--'))
    $delimiter = '--';

  $line = str_replace('/', $delimiter, $line);

  // Case 5 looks like case 2 now.

  $parts = explode($delimiter, $line);
  $table = array_map(function($part) { return array_map('trim', explode(',', $part)); }, $parts);

  // At this point, table contains a grid with missing values.

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($table); $i++) {
    $row = $table[$i];

    // Trivial case (case 1 and 3), go on.
    if (2 == count($row))
      continue;

    if (preg_match('/^[A-Z]{2}$/', $row[0])) {
      // Missing city; seek backwards.
      $find = $i;
      while (2 != count($table[$find]))
        $find--;
      $table[$i] = [$table[$find][0], $row[0]];
    } else {
      // Missing state; seek forwards.
      $find = $i;
      while (2 != count($table[$find]))
        $find++;
      $table[$i][] = $table[$find][1];
    }
  }
  return $table;
}
```

It's not pretty and it's slow. It does cover all my cases and since I'm doing an ETL process the speed isn't paramount. There's also no error detection, which works in my particular case.